# Is this writing pattern called an attribution?

Tags: journalism

I had posted this question under "academic-writing" and on there someone believes that it might be called "attribution". Can anyone confirm if this is correct or where I can find a reference?

> Original Question:

I'm curious to know if this style of writing (pattern) has a name. They can sometimes take up almost a full paragraph giving background about a specific person or subject when introducing them into an article.

"At the Saturday briefing, Dr. Stephen Hahn, commissioner of the Food and Drug Administration, co-author of the critically acclaimed book "XYZ", told us that..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed an example of attribution.

[This](https://www.thoughtco.com/attribution-when-writing-news-stories-2074313) website lists 4 distinct styles of attribution, and your example is the first kind:

> 1. On the record: All statements are directly quotable and attributable, by name and title, to the person making the statement. This is the most valuable type of attribution.
>
> Example: "The U.S. has no plans to invade Iran," said White House press secretary Jim Smith.

Your statement is simply the reverse. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you sooooo much! This helps me immensely!